# Laravel: Relationship for a model that belongs to two different models

Tags: laravel, relationship

I'm looking for the correct relationship where each `Membership` model has many `Vote` models and each `Vote` model has one `Membership` model.
Similarly, each `User` model has many `Vote` models and each `Vote` model has one `User` model.
The same `Vote` model can belong to a `Membership` model as well as a `User` model.
I was considering to use a `Has One Through` relationship but it doesn't work.
So this is what I have so far:

> memberships: hasMany Vote
> id - integer
> name - string
>
> users: hasMany Vote
> id - integer
> name - string
>
> votes: belongsTo Membership, belongsTo User
> id - integer
> choice - string
> membership_id - integer
> user_id - integer

```
$vote = Vote::create(['choice' => 'yes']);
$membership->save($vote);
$user->save($vote);
...
$user = $membership->vote->user; 
$membership = $user->vote->membership;
```

But I'm not sure if it's the way to go.
Any advice ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want each Membership and each User to have many Vote models, and each Vote model should belong to either a Membership or a User right ?

Comment: @KhayamKhan Not exactly. Each user votes (yes/no) for a membership request. Once done, the vote is associated to the membership and to the user (the author of the vote).

Comment: It seems like you want a many to many relationship between User and Membership through the Vote model, where each vote not only belongs to a user and a membership but also stores the choice made by the user I am right ?

Comment: @KhayamKhan Correct.

Comment: okay please wait while i write the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hasMany in Membership and User models to define a one-to-many relationship with Vote.
Use belongsTo in Vote to define the inverse relationship, indicating that it belongs to both a Membership and a User.

**Membership model:**

```
class Membership extends Model
{
    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vote::class, 'membership_id');
    }
}
```

**User model:**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vote::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Vote model:**

```
class Vote extends Model
{
    public function membership()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Membership::class, 'membership_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

You can easily attach the votes to the membership or user,

```
$membership->votes()->create([
    // fields of votes other than membership_id
]);
$user->votes()->create([
    // fields of votes other than user_id
]);
```

and can fetch records very easily like,

```
$user = User::with('votes')->get();
$user = User::with('votes')->find($user_id);
// same above for membership
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The relationship between the models is basically what I already have. Now I have to test the creating and the fetching of the models as you do it. Thanks again.

Comment: no issues, you can also do it as many to many by creating a pivot table membership_user.